# what are the possible ways to divide a square as 4 equal parts

Tags: diagram

[image: []

what are the possible ways to divide a square as 4 equal parts

Comment: Can you elaborate on the question ? Is it about geometry or just how to do it in a given software ?

Comment: You will almost certainly get a better answer to this on [math.se].

Comment: Without some context I don't think this has anything to do with graphic design and I'm no mathematician but I'm sure the answer is: infinitely many ways...

Comment: This is about math, not graphic design

Comment: Yeap there is an infinite says to do that.

Comment: It depends on the limits of how one can divide it. With no restrictions, the count is theoretically infinite

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a homework. In reality yes, it has something to do with graphic design.

It is the kind of analisis of shapes and transformations that one make in the first semesters of a carreer.

You really need to imagine things, see things, and feel the answer.

A) It is enough if you simply modify some center lines in equal relationship to each sub-square, and rotate that segment 90°.

B) If you think of a square as part of a multi dimensional square pattern universe :o), you can invade each square with a twin square. You have two separated shapes, but together they are simply a split shape, but all 4 splited shapes are equal, so it is valid.

C) And if you think outside the box, I mean, the square, you can join this pices, move them an assemble them. Combine this with the first case and you achive interesting patterns.

[image]

This is the kind of thinking that you need to develop. But I am worried if you are studying design. You need to explore, not simply ask someone else.